# How to get Facebook Page News Feeds only but Without FaceBook Login in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am working on iOS 5 and xcode 4.2.

I already read lots of links from this site but do not get any working answer, I have facebook SDK API's link and I also tried with Graph User API.

Please anybody have any example, snippet code or anything give me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without user login how do you expect news feeds?

Comment: Facebook Page Feed Like "Google" OR "UNICEF" with login or Without Login if Possible.